# Input Defines Multiple Set Names & Content in Python

Tags: python, set

I need to read multiple lines of user input to create multiple sets. The first word in each line should become that set's name. So, if I were to input 'Red Bob Sam Luke', I should create a set called 'Red' and populate it with 'Bob, Sam, Luke' as Red is their favourite colour. A new line of input should then allow me to enter more colours and people to create more sets. I need to compare the sets at the end, but that's not what's thrown me. I just can't work out how to get the input to make multiple sets. I need some sort of loop that will create a new set each time. The program should break if I enter nothing. I've made some headway with taking the input and defining and populating a set but have hit a brick wall thereafter.

```
info = input('Line: ').split()
info[0] = set(info[1:])
```

Many thanks in anticipation!

Comment: you about dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something to hold the list of sets. A dictionary, perhaps?

```
info = input('Line: ').split()
setdict[info[0]] = set(info[1:])
```

though that has the problem of colliding names - you haven't described what should happen in the case of input like:

```
Red Bob Sam Luke
Red Rue Amy Lila
```

...do you want one set, or two? if one, do you want the first set, the last set, or the sum of both sets?

Comment: closing bracket is missing before dot

Comment: At the end, I need to be able to compare the sets and find out if people only like one colour. So if Luke only liked Red, then it would print 'Luke only likes one colour' - and the same for anyone else on another line. If that's not the case, it should print 'Everyone likes more than one colour!' We can assume that there won't be colliding names for the sake of the activity I'm working through. Oh and it's a sets activity, so the dictionary route would work but not be what they were after.

Comment: Then the above code will work, creating a dict of sets (`setdict`) where the dict key is the set name and the dict value is the set itself.